# Why can't functions with same name and argument type check can't co-exist?

Tags: c++, c++17, sfinae

I expected the 2 definitions below to co-exist because i am adding a type checking code but it gives error as already declared. Why so and what needs to be changed?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<class T, class = std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<T>>>
bool is_even(T value)
{
    return ((value % 2) == 0);
}

template<class T, class = std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point_v<T>>>
bool is_even(T value)
{
    std::cout << "\n Floating point version ";
    return false;
}
    
int main()
{
    std::cout << "is_even (4) = " << std::boolalpha << is_even(4);
    std::cout << "is_even (4.4) = " << std::boolalpha << is_even(4.4);
}
```

Errors as below

```
Error(s):
462942513/source.cpp:13:6: error: redefinition of ‘template<class T, class> bool is_even(T)’
 bool is_even(T value)
      ^~~~~~~
462942513/source.cpp:7:6: note: ‘template<class T, class> bool is_even(T)’ previously declared here
 bool is_even(T value)
      ^~~~~~~
462942513/source.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
462942513/source.cpp:22:69: error: no matching function for call to ‘is_even(double)’
     std::cout << "is_even (4.4) = " << std::boolalpha << is_even(4.4);
                                                                     ^
462942513/source.cpp:7:6: note: candidate: template<class T, class> bool is_even(T)
 bool is_even(T value)
      ^~~~~~~
462942513/source.cpp:7:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
```

Even this syntax without default arguments doesn't work

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<class T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<T>>>
bool is_even(T value)
{
    return ((value % 2) == 0);
}

template<class T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point_v<T>>>
bool is_even(T value)
{
    return false;
}

int main()
{
   
    std::cout << "is_even (4) = " << std::boolalpha << is_even(4) << "\n";
    std::cout << "is_even (4.4) = " << std::boolalpha << is_even(4.4) << "\n";
}
```

Comment: The problem is well described in the **Notes** [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if).

Comment: You should also take a look at [constaints and concepts](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints).

Comment: Summarizing: `class = std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<T>>` only provides a _default value_ for the second parameter of `is_even`. There's nothing stopping someone from trying to instantiate `is_even<std::istream, void>`, at which point the `enable_if_t` doesn't even get used and there's no way to tell which of the two templates that function is supposed to be an instantiation of.

Comment: @NathanPierson : Why `template<class T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point_v<T>>* = nullptr>` works but `template<class T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point_v<T>>` doesn't?   I think even `template<class T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point_v<T>>* = nullptr>` is providing default value only as nullptr.

Comment: If you don't want default parameter, you need to specify it during instantiation https://godbolt.org/z/6j35er3zG

Comment: @nhatnq : my intention is to not specify int, float etc while making the invocation. And why do you have the pointer * in your code after enable_if?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why so and what needs to be changed?

From [std::enable_if 's documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if):

> A common mistake is to declare two function templates that differ only in their default template arguments. This does not work **because the declarations are treated as redeclarations of the same function template (*default template arguments are not accounted for in function template equivalence*)**.

One way to solve this problem in your given example would be to use the `enable_if_t` expression when specifying the return type of the function template instead of as a default argument, as shown below:

```
template<class T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<T>,bool> is_even(T value)
{
    return ((value % 2) == 0);
}

template<class T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point_v<T>, bool> is_even(T value)
{
    std::cout << "\n Floating point version ";
    return false;
}
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/EFfQjEJHyF)

##### Solution 2

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<class T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<T>, bool> = true>
auto is_even(T value)
{
    return ((value % 2) == 0);
}

template<class T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point_v<T>, bool> = true>
auto is_even(T value)
{
    std::cout << "\n Floating point version ";
    return false;
}
    
int main()
{
    std::cout << "is_even (4) = " << std::boolalpha << is_even(4);
    std::cout << "is_even (4.4) = " << std::boolalpha << is_even(4.4);
}
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/lYB2sNB8M)

Comment: Why can't i use like this? `template<class T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point_v<T>>>` . Now there is no default argument. Still why it complains. I don't want to use the syntax you mentioned in your response.

Comment: @Helena Because then the second template parameter is a **non-type template parameter** instead of being a *type template parameter*. See [this](https://onlinegdb.com/UG8Vs2Kub) and [this](https://onlinegdb.com/hcKwZQSE1) demo.

Comment: Is non-type template parameter a parameter with no type? Or is it something else? I thought in my case the type is int or float?

Comment: @Helena If you like the syntax that you mentioned, see [this](https://onlinegdb.com/NSPkAOgtz) demo. I have added this example at the end of my edited answer. Check it out.

Comment: i am having hard time understanding this line `template<class T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<T>, bool> = 0>` . Whats the purpose of bool here and why equae to 0?

Comment: @Helena `is_even<int, 5>(4)` was just an example that i gave you to demonstrate the fact that the second template parameter is a non-type parameter since it wasn't clear to you. You asked that *"why cant i use like this: `template<class T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point_v<T>>>`"*. So to answer this i gave that example.

Comment: Yes i understood the demos but unable to make a mental picture of `template<class T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<T>, bool> = 0>` . Why we need bool and why equate to 0?

Comment: @Helena I think you need to look at how `std::enable_if` works. I mean the basics of it. Also, in the statement `template<class T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point_v<T>, bool>`, the `bool` is there so that when the condition for `enable_if` evaluates to `true` then the second template parameter will be a `bool`.

Comment: So when the the condition for enable_if evaluates to true then the second template parameter will be a bool and you have given it a default value of 0? Is this correct?

Comment: @Helena Yes. I have modified my example(solution 2 in my answer) so that it will make more sense now why have we used `bool`. See [demo](https://onlinegdb.com/kRtsrX09n). Check out my updated answer(Solution 2 in particular). Here i have used `decltype(K)` where if the condition of `enable_if` evaluate to `true` then `K` will be a **non-type** template parameter of type `bool` and so `decltype(K)` will be `bool`.